# Solve for $z$, $ z = \int\frac{p(x)}{x-z^*}\mathrm{d}x $

Tags: probability-distributions, complex-numbers, functional-equations, integral-equations

Let $p(x)$ be a probability distribution. Without further information is it possible to solve the following equation for the unknown $z\in \mathbb{C}$ ?

$$ z = \int\frac{p(x)}{x-z^*}\mathrm{d}x $$ Where $z^*$ represents the complex conjugate of z.

I tried feeding various methods such as feeding this expression in the Euler-Lagrange equation, but I am starting to believe that without further information on $p(x)$ this equation is the best we can get.

Any remark or advice is always appreciated, thank you very much.

Comment: I wouldn't think it's possible. Imagine $p(x)=\delta(x-x_0)$ a delta function. Then $z=z(x_0)$ will depend on $x_0$, which you don't know unless you know $p$ to begin with.

Comment: I think I agree, thank you for sharing your point. I will wait for a bit longer to see whether someone has perhaps an other view.

Comment: Maybe using residue theorem ?